# magento : get tier price of product

Tags: product, php, api, tierprice

i want to get Tier Price via API in magento , i use method described in this Link but i have problam in get tier_price , it`s return only price from catalogProductTierPriceEntity content ! customer_group_id and website and qty is missing

i use this code :

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey'); 

$result = $proxy->catalogProductInfo($sessionId, '4');
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following way.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login($apiUser,$apiKey);
$productId = 166;
$result = $client->catalogProductAttributeTierPriceInfo(
    $session,
    $productId
);
print_r($result);
```

For more information click [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductTierPrice/catalog_product_attribute_tier_price.info.html) .